# IF formula to compare several cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Having problems with "IF" in Excel.

I want to compare Cell A2 with cells B2, B4, (...), B100 from another sheet.
How do I write the formula?

Comment: By compare do you mean check equality? What is the expected result?

Comment: Your question isn't answerable as written.  "Compare" could mean anything.  You give a list of cells you want to use that has no discernable pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the function [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1).

Syntax: `VLOOKUP (lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])`

With Vlookup you can search for a match and bring the value in another cell of the same row of the match.

Now, in **Sheet1** cell `B2`you can put: `=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$100,1,FALSE)`.

It will look for a match of the value of `A2` in the first column of the range `Sheet2!$B$2:$B$100`, and bring the content of column `1` of that range.

`FALSE` means that it will look for the exact match.